# placement of dynamically added buttons in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have dynamically created a bunch of buttons. I gave a fixed width to each of them. I want it to be added until space is available to its parents and when it overlaps with some other nodes, it will automatically go to the next line in order to avoid collision. I want it to be responsive at different screen sizes.

```
for(Data i:datas){
  Button btn=new Button(i.getName());
  anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(btn);
}
```

I want to arrange the buttons in a new line only when the buttons in the first line have covered its total width. How can I accomplish it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a [`FlowPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html). More generally, read the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) to get an overview of the different layout panes available.

Answer (score 0):

James_D provided a great resource—there's a built in layout for anything you need and FlowPane has what you want here.

Using your example, just swap out your AnchorPane for FlowPane:

```
FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();

for(Data i:datas){
  Button btn=new Button(i.getName());
  flowPane.getChildren().addAll(btn);
}
```

To make it responsive (i.e. expand and contract with the parent container/stage), bind the FlowPane's width and height to those of its parent:

```
flowPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
flowPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
```

Comment: You shouldn't really need to bind the width and height of the flow pane: just use the appropriate layout pane for the flow pane's parent (with some configuration if necessary).

Comment: You're right. In most cases, putting it in an AnchorPane or GridPane will take care of the resizing.